# NullPointerException in put method of hashmap in chat class

Tags: java, oop

I keep getting null pointer exception when I try to put into messages
( I have removed all unnecessary code)
I dont get the error when I initialize messages inside add function
How can I resolve this?

```
class Chat {

    HashMap< Integer, String> messages;

    void Chat() {
        this.messages = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(int id, String newMessage) {
        if (!newMessage.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(newMessage + "   "
                    + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
            this.messages.put(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)),
                    newMessage);
            System.out.println(messages.values() + "Added to hashset");
        }

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Chat obj = new Chat();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                obj.add(i + 1, str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `void Chat ()` <- this is a method, not a constructor. Am I correct to assume that you intended this to be a constructor? If yes remove the return type (`void`).

Comment: Why are you doing `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id))`?